# Can server send message to client using TCP?

Tags: http, tcp, websocket, server, client

I  only did HTML/HTTP before, and did some websockets in our website, now I'm assigned a task that there will be client and server, and client will connect to server's IP, and server will send some commands to client.

I was originally thinking using HTTP and websocket to do this task, but was told by someone that I should use TCP instead of HTTP/websocket.

Since I have no idea of TCP, could you please tell me is TCP only capable of this task?

Comment: HTTP uses TCP. TCP is a transport layer protocol and HTTP is an application layer protocol.

Comment: What is the client?  Custom app?  Web page in a browser?

Comment: @jfriend00 custom app

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom client (e.g. not a web app in a browser), it can make a plain TCP connection to your server if it wants to.  But, every transmission on TCP needs some sort of data format that both sides are using (typically called a "protocol") so it is generally easier to use an existing protocol rather than reinvent your own.  Things like HTTP, webSocket, FTP, etc... are protocols that define actions to be carried out and data formats.

So, typically you would find a protocol that matches well what you're trying to do and get an existing library to implement that protocol on both client and server.  This will generally save you a lot of work writing and parsing data you send over the connection.

Which protocol to select depends entirely upon what you're trying to accomplish with the connection which you have not shared so we can't make any specific recommendations.

> I was originally thinking using HTTP and websocket to do this task, but was told by someone that I should use TCP instead of HTTP/websocket.

Did you ask them why they were telling you that?  HTTP is extremely universal and simple to use, but it is a request/response protocol (client A sends a request and server B provides a response and then the connection is done).  That works great for some types of things, not so good for other types of things.

webSocket is actually initiated over HTTP and then switches protocols to the webSocket data frame format and is designed as a persistent connection that can be long lived and can send data in both directions.  For example, a client could connection to a server over a webSocket and then the serve could send stock quote updates every few seconds as they arrives on the server.  The client would just sit and listen for updates to arrives.

> Since I have no idea of TCP, could you please tell me is TCP only capable of this task?

TCP is certainly capable.  TCP is a lower level transport layer that many other things like HTTP are built on top of.  You can do just about any type of networking you want over TCP, but because it's low level, you will have to design a lot of your communication mechanisms yourself from scratch.  You would typically first look for an existing protocol (that runs on top of TCP) that matches the needs of your connection and use the work that someone else has already done rather than building your own protocol from scratch.